# Nginx reverse proxy in docker for express.js server

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx

In docker, I have a client facing server container, an api server container and a nginx container that is exposed outside at port `8000`. After running api and client server container, I am running nginx container with has `nginx.conf` replaced with the following:

```
events {
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://server:9002;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://client:9001;
        }
    }
}
```

I can verify `client` server working properly through nginx by making request to `http://localhost:8000` or `http://localhost:8000/blah`. But if I go to the URL `http://localhost:8000/api`, it redirects to `http://localhost/api` and fails to connect.

I verified that the `server` container is actually running by running it with a separate exposed port and it returns result on request as expected. How would I fix this ?

Comment: Can you share complete code from Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, if it has? By the configuration, you should access your instances by port `80`, if you access `http://localhost/api` should redirect to server:9002, if you access `http://localhost` should redirect to `http://client:9002`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been an environmental variable issue. I had `PORT` env var set on docker-compose.yml but not in Docekrfile, adding it solved the issue. Removing `PORT` env var from docker-compose.yml still works.